# How do I chain if the Pokemon I want isn't on a route with any grass?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm trying to catch a shiny Skitty on [Route 4](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kalos_Route_4) (the only place to catch one) via the [chaining method](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1ot6ex/chaining_tutorial/). The problem is that the chaining method requires you to use the [Poke Radar](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Radar) which doesn't seem to work with flowers (flowers seem to act almost exactly like grass in X/Y), and Route 4 just so happens to have no grass at all.

So, how can I chain if the Poke Radar doesn't work in flowers?

Comment: In what way does the Radar "not seem to work with flowers"?  [Bulbapedia explicitly says](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Poké_Radar#In_X_and_Y) "[I]t can be used in flower beds the same way as in tall grass."

Comment: @jwodder I feel really stupid now. As it turns out I had my bike on, and it wouldn't let me use it.

Comment: This question could still apply to Pokemon found in caves or other non-grass areas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the Poke Radar *can* be used in flower beds (just like grass). However I made the mistake of keeping my bike turned on which was causing the Poke Radar to not work (Moms words echoed... blah, blah, blah).

Answer (score 0):

The pokeradar does work with Tall grass and flowers but most people say that using it with flowers is a lot harder than with normal grass. (It's actually the only method to increase your chances of gettting a shiny ditto as far as i know)

Note however that the radar doesn't work within caves, on water and on mounted encounters (riding through snow for example).

For caves you still got the option of horde farming and on water you could chain fish to increase your shiny encounter rate. For pokemon encountered in other areas (mounted) there is currently no known way to increase the chance of a shiny.

Comment: ... besides breeding.